# How to Avoid adding additional string on url

Tags: jquery

I want to change the URL of the product when a swatches are selected.
example:

```
Towel 1
color: blue
size 9x12
```

The product url would be:
`http://somedomain.com/product/towel-1/?attribute_color=blue&attribute_size=9%27+x+12%27`

But whenever I hovered other input:radio it adds on the link and not replacing the link. Am I missing something?

here's my code:

```js
jQuery('.tax-product_cat input:radio').hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).click();
  var attrSizeVal = jQuery("input[name='attribute_size']:checked").val();
  var attrColorVal = jQuery("input[name='attribute_color']:checked").val();
  var prod = jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href');
  var convert = attrSizeVal;
  convert = encodeURIComponent(convert).replace('%20', '+').replace('%20', '+').replace("'", "%27").replace("'", "%27");
  var link = '?attribute_color=' + attrColorVal + '&attribute_size=' + convert;
  var newURL = prod + link;
  jQuery('#products li').each(function(){
    if(jQuery('input:radio').is(':checked')) { 
      jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href', newURL);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant html of the page or maybe even a jsfiddle for further clarification? (It would help to see if there are multiple radio buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into your code

```js
jQuery('.tax-product_cat input:radio').hover(function() {
  jQuery(this).click();
  var attrSizeVal = jQuery("input[name='attribute_size']:checked").val();
  var attrColorVal = jQuery("input[name='attribute_color']:checked").val();
  var prod = jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href');
  var convert = attrSizeVal;
  convert = encodeURIComponent(convert).replace('%20', '+').replace('%20', '+').replace("'", "%27").replace("'", "%27");
  var link = '?attribute_color=' + attrColorVal + '&attribute_size=' + convert;
  var newURL = prod + link;
  jQuery('#products li').each(function(){
    if(jQuery('input:radio').is(':checked')) { 
      jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href', newURL);  // ----- Problem is here
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

When you are reassigning the value of `anchor tag` using the bloew code

```
jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href', newURL);
```

And next time when you hover & fetching the `href` value using the below code, it recevies the updated `href` value of newURL.

```
var prod = jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href');
```

Either you set the `anchor tag` value in the begining & onhover just click.
Take out the below code from `hover` method

```
jQuery('#products li').each(function(){
  if(jQuery('input:radio').is(':checked')) { 
    jQuery('ul#products li a').attr('href', newURL);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Please provide you `HTML` code, so that I can provide you exact solution.

Comment: everytime the input button is hovered the link is extending too much
I get it now that is why my link extends like this: http://somedomain.com/product/towel-1/?attribute_color=blue&attribute_size=9%27+x+12%27?attribute_color=Blue&attribute_size=9%27+x+12%27?attribute_color=Blue&attribute_size=9%27+x+12%27?attribute_color=Blue&attribute_size=9%27+x+12%27